# iOS7 iAd Interstitial Crash upon didUnload "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad was unloaded from this banner"

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, iad, interstitial

Hi I managed to implement iAd Interstitial successfully. During ad load, it shows an interstitial iAd (full screen). Everything is ok. But if I leave the app for some time,
whenever the delegate interstitialAdDidUnload is called, the delegate interstitialAdDidFailWithError is called, followed by a crash!

I have no idea why.

Here is my delegates:

```
#pragma mark iAd Interstitial

//Interstitial iAd
-(void)showFullScreenAd {
    //Check if already requesting ad
    if (requestingAd == NO) {
        [ADInterstitialAd release];
        iAdstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
        iAdstitial.delegate = self;
        self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;
        [self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
        NSLog(@"interstitialAdREQUEST");
        requestingAd = YES;
    }//end if
}

-(void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    iAdstitial = nil;
    if (interstitialAd!=nil) [interstitialAd release];
    requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"interstitialAd didFailWithERROR");
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    [self showChartboost];


}

-(void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {

    if ([self requestInterstitialAdPresentation]) {
        NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidPRESENT");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not avail");
        // NOT AVAIL SO GO ADMOB

        [self showChartboost];
    }


}

-(void)interstitialAdDidUnload:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    if (interstitialAd!=nil)[interstitialAd release];
    requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidUNLOAD");
}

-(void)interstitialAdActionDidFinish:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    if (interstitialAd!=nil) [interstitialAd release];
    requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidFINISH");
}
```

The log shows:

```
2014-09-06 18:14:51.557 [1467:60b] interstitialAdDidUNLOAD
2014-09-06 18:14:51.557 [1467:60b] interstitialAd didFailWithERROR
2014-09-06 18:14:51.559 [1467:60b] Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad was unloaded from this banner" UserInfo=0x11998d20 {ADInternalErrorCode=7, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad was unloaded from this banner}
(lldb)
```

after which it crash.